# NumPy masking issue -- What am I missing?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I'm plotting diet information using matplotlib, where the x-axis represents a range of dates, and the y-axis represents the number of calories consumed. Not too complicated that, but there is one snag: not all dates have calorie information, and it would make most sense to leave those out rather than do some sort of interpolation/smoothing.

I found several good examples of using numpy masks for such situations, but it seems I'm not getting something straight, as the code that I *think* should produce the results I want doesn't change anything.

Have a look:

`calories_list_ma = np.ma.masked_where(calories_list == 0, calories_list)`
`plt.plot(datetimes_list, calories_list_ma, marker = 'x', color = 'r', ls = '-')`

Which produces this: [image: Sample Output]

I just want there to be an unplotted gap in the line for 9-23.

And actually, I know my use of masked_where must be incorrect, because when I print calories_list_ma.mask, the result is 'False'. Not a list, as it should be, showing which values are masked/unmasked with True and False.

Can someone set me straight?

Thanks so much!

Comment: What is `calories_list` initially?  If it is really a list, `calories_list == 0` will indeed return False, resulting in no mask.  You need to make it into a numpy array first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing from the name that your `calories_list` is a list.  If it is a list `calories_list == 0` will return one value, namely False, since the list does not equal the value 0.  `masked_where` will then dutifully set the mask to False, resulting in an unmasked copy of your list.

You need to do `calories_list = np.array(calories_list)` first to make it into a numpy array.  Unlike lists, numpy arrays have the "broadcasting" feature whereby `calories_list == 0` compares each element individually to zero.

Comment: D'oh! Thanks so much. Outputs as expected now.

Answer (score -1):

try using

```
calories_list_ma = np.ma.masked[calories_list == 0]
```